# How to confirm whether a given function is a joint distribution of two r.v.s

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given the functions
$$F(x,y) = \begin{cases}1-e^{-x-y}\quad \text{if} \ x,y \geq 0,\\ 0 \qquad \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}
$$
$$F(x,y) = \begin{cases}1-e^{-x}-xe^{-y}\quad \text{if} \ 0 \leq x \leq y,\\ 1-e^{-x}-ye^{-y}\quad \text{if} \ 0\leq y \leq x,\\0 \qquad \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}
$$
Check whether these are joint distribution of some pair $(X,Y)$. If they are, find the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ separately.

How would I tackle this?
I can do this if it's single variables, I would just differentiate and then check if it satisfies the PMF properties but I'm unsure for two variables.

Also, is the last part just finding the marginal densities?

Answer (score 1):

In general a join cumulative distribution $F(x_1,x_2\cdots)$ must be monotonically non-decreasing for each of its variables $x_1,x_2,\cdots$. And this is not the case for the second case, here's a plot of $F$ as a function of $y$ for $x=1$

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How would I show the first one is/isn't one?

Comment: @Mr.BromwichI I think the first one has all the familiar symptoms for being a joint cumulative distribution function: goes asymptotically to 1, is continuous and increasing in both variables

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to show it asymptocailyl goes to 1 in two variables.

Comment: @Mr.BromwichI Intuitively if both $x$ and $y$ increase, then $x + y$ increases. This means that $e^{-(x+y)}$ becomes smaller and so $1- e^{-(x+y)}$ approaches 1